# C# skips for loop?

Tags: c#, list, loops, foreach

i have one little question. When i compile and run this code the WriteLine method is called before the foreach statement has iterated. This causes System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException when WriteLine is called because the element has not been set yet by the foreach loop. I thought c# progressed downwards through the code and waited until for and while loops completed before continuing downwards like in c++. Could somebody explain this to me and tell me how to wait until the foreach loop before continuing execution.

Thanks!

```
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    var items = row.ChildNodes.Where(y => y.Name.Equals("td"));
    List<string> entries = new List<string>();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
         entries.Add(item.InnerText);
    }

    //This is executed before the foreach loop has iterated through all the items?
    Debug.WriteLine(entries.ElementAt(0));
}
```

Comment: `This is executed before the foreach loop has iterated through all the items` No, it definitely isn't. This is much more likely that `items` is empty

Comment: Have you debugged to see what it's actually doing, line by line, observing the variables?

Comment: check `Debug.WriteLine(items.Any());`

Comment: Put a WriteLine call in your loop and see what happens

Comment: or `Debug.WriteLine(items.Count());`  like this: `if (items.Any()) {Debug.WriteLine(entries.ElementAt(0));}`

Comment: Yes, As @KevinGosse mentioned it is very much likely that your items is not having anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that

```
var items = row.ChildNodes.Where(y => y.Name.Equals("td"));
```

is empty.

foreach (var item in items) executes but does nothing.

Comment: Thank you! I seem to have forgotten to check that.

Answer (score 3):

> is called before the foreach statement... This causes System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException when WriteLine

No, that's not causing the exception. This exception is raised if you use [`Enumerable.ElementAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb299233(v=vs.110).aspx) on an empty collection. That also explains why the `foreach` loop is "skipped".

> `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`: index is less than 0 or greater than or
>   equal to the number of elements in source.

by the way, you can simplify the code:

```
var entries = row.ChildNodes
    .Where(item => item.Name.Equals("td"))
    .Select(item => item.InnerText)
    .ToList();
```